# javascript click function not working on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, onclick

here is my javascript code. the problem is only the last create function is working properly but not other.for example as here i have 4 create() function only last one is working properly. if i have 3 then the 3rd one will work fine but not others........please suggest what is wrong with this code....please help i'm new to javasript.

[Please check my code in codepen here](http://codepen.io/vasurajoria/pen/JdZWGe?editors=001)

```
window.onload=function()
{
var number_operation_table=document.getElementById('number_operation_table');


create('lt','<');
create('gteq','>=');
create('lteq','<=');
create('gt','>');


function create(prefix,operator)
{

number_operation_table.innerHTML+="<tr><td><input type='text' name='"+prefix+"_val1' id='"+prefix+"_val1'/>"+operator+"<input name='"+prefix+"_val2' type='text' id='"+prefix+"_val2'/></td>         <td><button id='check_"+prefix+"'>check</button></td>         <td id='"+prefix+"_result'></td>       </tr>";



 eval("var "+prefix+"check=document.getElementById('check_"+prefix+"');");
console.log(eval(prefix+"check"));
 console.log("button created with name:"+prefix+"check") ;

eval(prefix+"check.onclick=function()  {    calculate(prefix,operator);     };");


}

function calculate(prefix,operator)
{
var val1=parseInt((document.getElementById(prefix+'_val1')).value);
var val2=parseInt((document.getElementById(prefix+'_val2')).value);
var result_div=document.getElementById(prefix+'_result');



if((eval(''+val1+ operator +val2))==false)
  {

result_div.innerHTML="<span class='fail'>"+val1+ operator +val2 +" = false</span>";
  }

if((eval(''+val1+ operator +val2))==true)
  {
result_div.innerHTML="<span class='success'>true</span>";
   }

 }



};
```

Comment: Don't use `eval` to create dynamically named variables.

Comment: You only need an if-then-else in  calculate, not two if-then statements

Comment: @FelixKling is there any other technique with that we can create variable dynamically......i read about eval() from the following link after ur comment...thanks

Comment: @vogomatix corrected as it was my old code ...was making some chnages..thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You should not be creating dynamic variables at all. If you need something with dynamic names, use an object as a map. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects. Or if you don't needs specific names, use an array.

Comment: @FelixKling...i'm using window[] to create dynamic names. is it good or bad practice. below is my update code with window[]  plz see and suggest : http://codepen.io/vasurajoria/pen/JdZWGe

Answer (score 0):

Your problem (among others) is that when you concatenate to an element using `innerHTML` you destroy all the event listeners on the contents of that element. Every time you call create, your code destroys all the previously created `onclick` handlers.

Instead, try:

```
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
newRow.innerHTML = "<td><input type='text' name='"+prefix+"_val1' id='"+prefix+"_val1'/>"+operator+"<input name='"+prefix+"_val2' type='text' id='"+prefix+"_val2'/></td>         <td><button id='check_"+prefix+"'>check</button></td>         <td id='"+prefix+"_result'></td>";

number_operation_table.appendChild( newRow);
```

Alternatively, you could have a single event listener attached to the table instead of one for each button

**Other issues:**

You should not need 'eval' in the `create` method at all:

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('check_"+prefix+"');
myButton.onclick = function() { calculate( prefix, operator) };
```

You should only need one test in the calculate method:

```
if((eval(''+val1+ operator +val2))==false) {
  result_div.innerHTML="<span class='fail'>"+val1+ operator +val2 +" = false</span>";
} else {

  result_div.innerHTML="<span class='success'>true</span>";
}
```

Comment: thanks u so much for explaining it very well. it is working now..... as i'm creating these rows dynamically with different operators and displaying this result in different column in relative row, i have no idea that with single event listener how that can be achieved...as each button is performing different operation how that possible with single event listener....can u give some reference for this ..plz guide.

Comment: I normally work with JQuery or similar, but Google for `javascript delegated event` and `javascript event bubbling` to find out more on how this works.